# Why can't I explicitly source a file using su -c?

Tags: bash, bashrc, source, su

I'm trying to get `su` to `source /home/ghost/.bashrc`, but it doesn't seem to load the contents:

```
$ su -l -c 'source /home/ghost/.bashrc; nvm' ghost
-su: nvm: command not found
```

I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage Node versions. Nvm is normally sourced by the `ghost` user in `/home/ghost/.bashrc`:

```
# in /home/ghost/.bashrc
export NVM_DIR="/home/ghost/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

I found from [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20953/sudo-source-command-not-found) [questsions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100146/roots-bashrc-not-executing-on-sudo-i) that putting the `nvm` init code in `/home/ghost/.profile` makes `nvm` available to `su -l` since it starts a login shell.

**I still can't figure out why I can't `source` the file explicitly.** Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: It's `nvm.sh`, not `nvm`. Also you don't need `-l`:  `su -c 'source /home/ghost/.bashrc; nvm.sh' ghost`

Comment: Pretty sure it's supposed to be `nvm`. At least, that's what they suggest in [their README](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage). EIther way, that command doesn't work either unless I put the `nvm` init stuff in `~/.profile`. For some reason I can't source anything explicitly from `su -c`.

Comment: How did you determine that the failure to find `nvm` means that the file is not being sourced? Where *is* `nvm`, and does /home/ghost/.bashrc add that location to the `PATH`? if so, how?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, I read "This loads nvm" and thought `"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` was used to start it automatically.

Comment: Please, add output of this to your question: `ls -ld /home/ghost/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Comment: @steeldriver - the code in the bashrc loads nvm. Since I can't use nvm, bashrc wasn't sourced. When I added `echo` statements to the bashrc they also failed to print. I'll edit the question to add some more info.

Comment: @all - figured it out. The default `/home/ghost/.bashrc` had code that halted execution if the shell wasn't being run in interactive mode. Starting from a blank `.bashrc` or moving `nvm` to the stop solved the problem. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The file **was** getting sourced, but execution was stopped when it reached this `case` statement, which will only continue if it is being sourced in a shell in interactive mode.

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

The variable `$-` represents the flags with which the current shell was initialized. If it doesn't see `i` (the flag for interactive mode), the code will return. Because the shell wasn't being run in interactive mode, `source .bashrc` stopped when it reached that `case` statement.

For reference, the output of `echo $-` when using a normal interactive shell is `himBH`. The output of `su -l -c 'echo $-' ghost`, however, I see `hBc`.

Moving the `nvm` lines above that statement solved the problem, as did putting them into a clean `.profile` or `.bashrc`.